# Cannot do a soft reset in the middle of a merge, but there is no merge to abort

Tags: git, git-merge

After mistakenly running `git stash pop` one extra time, I ran into merge conflicts. I tried to resolve them using an unfamiliar (for me) Git client but didn’t succeed fully, so I decided to quit merge manually and found it impossible.

I decided to post this question after I quit fiddling the unfamiliar Git client and executed the following commands directly in CLI, one after another, with paradoxical/contradictory outcomes:

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD
fatal: Cannot do a soft reset in the middle of a merge.

$ git merge --abort
fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing).
```

Additional information:

- `git status` showed one “unmerged path”, as “both modified”
- Running `git restore --staged <that path>` has resolved the situation and now I can do reset and there are no more “unmerged paths”
- My version of Git is 2.39.1

At this point, my interest is more academic than practical: is it a “nothing to see here, file a bug against Git about self-contradictory error messages” sort of situation, or is there something to be understood about how Git works that could provide insight into what’s going on?

Comment: `git reset` (no options, no commitish)

Comment: (Or `git reset --merge` if there are still unmerged entries.) But granted, it shouldn't be satisfying to your (sane) curiosity here. Part of the answer is that your index must have been left dirty after the unknown UI operations and confused the output of common commands. Resetting it does the trick.

Comment: Thanks knittl & Romain. Seems like I resolved the situation using another way, so I don’t know what your suggestions would’ve done. I’m curious, though, what weird inner state of Git repository could cause it to report “in the middle of a merge” in one command, but “no merge to abort” from another command.

Comment: Perhaps this question is pointless without a sample repo, I‘ll see if I can reproduce this weird state from scratch another day…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notice `in the middle of a merge` is really only just a best guess, not an acurate diagnostic. `git reset --soft` could perhaps be less specific here, since it doesn't go to great lengths to figure out the accurate circumstances.

A central hub when you work locally with Git is the "index" (formerly called "cache"), where Git caches the state of the files in the worktree that it tracks. The index also records the states of files when a conflict occurs during a "mergy" operation.

The thing is, "mergy" operations occur not only during an actual merge that was initiated by `git merge`, but also by many other operations. A prominent such operation is `git cherry-pick`. And `git stash pop` is another one.

The next thing is, there are certain operations that are not permitted when the index contains the records of a merge conflict. The most important operation that is prohibited in this situation is `git commit`. And, as you found out, `git reset --soft` is another one. For these operations, it is sufficient to inspect the index to know whether the operation can continue or must be stopped. When they do stop, the emit the error you saw, under the assumption that `a merge` is in progress. What they actually mean, however, is that you are `in the middle of a _mergy_ operation`.

`git merge`, however, is a fancier operation. In the case of conflicts, it not only leaves behind the index in a conflicted state, but it also leaves behind additional state that it needs when the user finally uses `git merge --continue` or `git commit` to conclude the merge after having resolved the conflicts. Therefore, `git merge --abort` has more clues to find out whether you are indeed in the middle of "a merge"; the particular one that you observed is that the file `MERGE_HEAD` is absent.

Answer (score 0):

[`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) supports multiple modes of operation:

```
SYNOPSIS
       git reset [-q] [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>...
       git reset [-q] [--pathspec-from-file=<file> [--pathspec-file-nul]] [<tree-ish>]
       git reset (--patch | -p) [<tree-ish>] [--] [<pathspec>...]
       git reset [--soft | --mixed [-N] | --hard | --merge | --keep] [-q] [<commit>]

DESCRIPTION
       In the first three forms, copy entries from <tree-ish> to the index. In
       the last form, set the current branch head (HEAD) to <commit>,
       optionally modifying index and working tree to match. The
       <tree-ish>/<commit> defaults to HEAD in all forms.
```

You are executing the last form with `git reset --soft HEAD`, which is:

```
   git reset [<mode>] [<commit>]
       This form resets the current branch head to <commit> and possibly
       updates the index (resetting it to the tree of <commit>) and the
       working tree depending on <mode>. Before the operation, ORIG_HEAD
       is set to the tip of the current branch. If <mode> is omitted,
       defaults to --mixed. The <mode> must be one of the following:

       --soft
           Does not touch the index file or the working tree at all (but
           resets the head to <commit>, just like all modes do). This
           leaves all your changed files "Changes to be committed", as git
           status would put it.
```

But you want to reset your index (reset all staged changes) by using one of the first three forms, using `git reset`:

```
   git reset [-q] [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>..., git reset [-q]
   [--pathspec-from-file=<file> [--pathspec-file-nul]] [<tree-ish>]
       These forms reset the index entries for all paths that match the
       <pathspec> to their state at <tree-ish>. (It does not affect the
       working tree or the current branch.)
```

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies what soft reset does; but the question is—how come resetting branch head not possible due to merge in progress, whereas aborting merge is not possible because no merge is in progress? Could it be a quirk in how `stash pop` does merge conflicts then?

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff `stash pop` only merges the index/worktree (and doesn't create a merge commit). `git merge` merges branches (and creates a merge commit). Both use the word "merge", but with a different meaning/context.